# Checkbox onchanged not updating in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my first time to develop a react application.

I am encountering problem when retrieving the checkedMap useState hook in react that does not update its status whenever the checkbox is checked then unchecked. The status seems saves the entries checked regardless if the next instance it was already unchecked.

**I accessed the value of by: Array.from(checkedMap.keys()));**

Scenario 1
Checkbox A - ticked
Checkbox B - ticked

checkedMap= id of Checkbox A and B

Scenario 2
Checkbox A - ticked
Checkbox B - unticked

**checkedMap= still id of Checkbox A and B**
//should be id of Checkbox A only

Thank you very much for your help.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

// Simulate a server
const getServerData = async ({ filters, sortBy, pageSize, pageIndex }) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

  // Ideally, you would pass this info to the server, but we'll do it here for convenience
  const filtersArr = Object.entries(filters);

  // Get our base data
  const res = await axios.get(
    `url here`
  );
  let rows = res.data;

  // Apply Filters
  if (filtersArr.length) {
    rows = rows.filter(row =>
      filtersArr.every(([key, value]) => row[key].includes(value))
    );
  }

  // Apply Sorting
  if (sortBy.length) {
    const [{ id, desc }] = sortBy;
    rows = [...rows].sort(
      (a, b) => (a[id] > b[id] ? 1 : a[id] === b[id] ? 0 : -1) * (desc ? -1 : 1)
    );
  }

  // Get page counts
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(rows.length / pageSize);
  const rowStart = pageSize * pageIndex;
  const rowEnd = rowStart + pageSize;

  // Get the current page
  rows = rows.slice(rowStart, rowEnd);

  return {
    rows,
    pageCount
  };
};


export default function({ infinite }) {
  const [checkedMap, setCheckedMap] = useState(new Map());
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const currentRequestRef = useRef();

  let newMap = new Map();

  const fetchData = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    // We can use a ref to disregard any outdated requests
    const id = Date.now();
    currentRequestRef.current = id;

    // Call our server for the data
    const { rows, pageCount } = await getServerData({
      filters,
      sortBy,
      pageSize,
      pageIndex
    });

    // If this is an outdated request, disregard the results
    if (currentRequestRef.current !== id) {
      return;
    }

    // Set the data and pageCount
    setData(rows);
    setState(old => ({
      ...old,
      pageCount
    }));

    rows.forEach(row => newMap.set(row, false));
    //setCheckedMap(newMap);

    setLoading(false);
  };

  const handleCheckedChange = transaction_seq => {
    let modifiedMap = checkedMap;
    modifiedMap.set(transaction_seq, !checkedMap.get(transaction_seq));
    setCheckedMap(modifiedMap);
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      Header: "Transaction(s)",
      className: "left",
      columns: [
        {
          id: "checkbox",
          accessor: "checkbox",
          Cell: ({ row }) => {
            return (
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                className="checkbox"
                checked={checkedMap.get(row.original.transaction_seq)}
                onChange={() =>
                  handleCheckedChange(row.original.transaction_seq)
                }
              />
            );
          },

const state = useTableState({ pageCount: 0 });

  const [{ sortBy, filters, pageIndex, pageSize }, setState] = state;

  const paginationButtons = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Button onClick={() => reprocessConfirmation()}>Reprocess</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => reprocessConfirmation()}>View Details</Button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  function reprocessConfirmation() {
    let confirmation = window.confirm(
      "Do you want to reprocess transaction sequence " +
        Array.from(checkedMap.keys())
    );

    if (confirmation === true) console.log(Array.from(checkedMap.keys()));
    else console.log("CANCEL");
  }

  function updateConfirmation() {
    let confirmation = window.confirm("Do you want to update transaction");
    if (confirmation === true) console.log("OK");
    else console.log("CANCEL");
  }

  // When sorting, filters, pageSize, or pageIndex change, fetch new data
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [sortBy, filters, pageIndex, pageSize]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <MyTable
        {...{
          data,
          checkedMap,
          paginationButtons,
          columns,
          infinite,
          state, // Pass the state to the table
          loading,
          manualSorting: true, // Manual sorting
          manualFilters: true, // Manual filters
          manualPagination: true, // Manual pagination
          disableMultiSort: true, // Disable multi-sort
          disableGrouping: true, // Disable grouping
          debug: true
        }}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just toggling the value on check and uncheck, the key will still be present when the checkbox is unchecked, You either must delete the key or look for a true value in the map instead of just checking if the key is present or not.

Code snippet for second solution

```
function reprocessConfirmation() {
    const keys = [];
    checkedMap.forEach((value, key) => {
        if(value) keys.push[key]
    })
    let confirmation = window.confirm(
      "Do you want to reprocess transaction sequence " +
        keys
    );

    if (confirmation === true) console.log(keys);
    else console.log("CANCEL");
  }
```